# Unexpected Zero Variance for an Unbiased Estimator: Is the Estimator Consistent?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, variance, convergence, estimators

$\newcommand{\szdb}[1]{\!\left[#1\right]}\newcommand{\szdp}[1]{\!\left(#1\right)}$
**Problem Statement:** Let $Y_1, Y_2,\dots,Y_n$ denote a random sample from the probability
density function
$$f(y)=
\begin{cases}
\theta\,y^{\theta-1},&0<y<1\\
0,&\text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$
where $\theta>0.$ Show that $\overline{Y}$ is a consistent estimator of
$\theta/(\theta+1).$ Note: This is Problem 9.13 in *Mathematical Statistics with Applications, 5th Ed.,* by Wackerly, Mendenhall, and Scheaffer.

**My Work So Far:** With a view towards using the variance test for consistent estimators (if the variance of an unbiased estimator goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty,$ then it is consistent), first we show that $E\szdp{\overline{Y}}=\theta/(\theta+1).$ We compute
\begin{align*}
E\szdp{\overline{Y}}
&=\frac1n\,\sum_{i=1}^n E(Y_i)\\
&=\frac1n\,\sum_{i=1}^n\int_0^1 y\,f(y)\,dy\\
&=\int_0^1y\,\theta\,y^{\theta-1}\,dy\\
&=\theta \szdb{\frac{y^{\theta+1}}{\theta+1}}_0^1\\
&=\frac{\theta}{\theta+1},
\end{align*}
as required. Now let us compute $V\szdp{\overline{Y}}.$ We need
\begin{align*}
E\szdp{\overline{Y}^2}
&=E\szdp{\szdp{\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nY_i}^{\!\!2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}E\szdp{\szdp{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i}\szdp{\sum_{j=1}^nY_j}}\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}E\szdp{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nY_iY_j}\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nE(Y_iY_j)\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nE(Y_i)E(Y_j)\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\theta^2}{(\theta+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{\theta^2}{(\theta+1)^2}.
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
V\szdp{\overline{Y}}
&=E\szdp{\overline{Y}^2}-\szdp{E\szdp{\overline{Y}}}^2\\
&=\frac{\theta^2}{(\theta+1)^2}-\frac{\theta^2}{(\theta+1)^2}\\
&=0.
\end{align*}

**My Question:** Clearly, this variance goes to zero as $n\to\infty,$ but I wouldn't expect zero variance for a random variable which can clearly exhibit some spread. However, I fail to see the error in my calculations. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$There's a mistake in $\Var(\bar Y)$. We can make life easier by using independence so
$$
\Var(\bar Y) = \frac 1n \Var(Y_1) = \frac 1n \left(\text E[Y_1^2] - \text E[Y_1]^2\right).
$$
$$
\text E[Y_1^2] = \int_0^1\theta y^{\theta+1}\,\text dy = \frac{\theta}{\theta+2}
$$
so all together
$$
\Var(\bar Y) = \frac 1n \left(\frac \theta{\theta+2} - \frac{\theta^2}{(\theta+1)^2}\right).
$$

What you missed is that $\text E\sum_{ij} Y_iY_j$ has $\text E[Y_i^2]$ terms in there.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying: in the $i,j$ sum, when $i=j,$ I can't use the same result as when $i\not=j.$ Is that right?

Comment: @AdrianKeister yeah exactly, really you have $$\text E\sum_{ij} Y_iY_j = n \text E[Y_1^2] + n(n-1)\text E[Y_1Y_2] $$. I've learned to be vigilant about this kind of error having made it many times myself :)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks much!

Comment: @AdrianKeister for sure! glad this helped